# get data or payload from actility using a node-red

Tags: node-red

I wanted to get payload data from Actility and fetch it using node-red. Right now I have created a device in Actility and add its application server into the public URL destination(using ngrok). I set the content type JSON. being honest, don't know where to start.is there any way I can get the JSON data or payload by fetching into the URL using node-red?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `http request` node to make Actility requests.

Don't forget to configure the response as JSON Object in the configuration form.

Comment: @F108: Does my answer solve your question? Is there remaining anything?